# Logger level setting for entire package hierarchy?

Tags: logback

Trying this with logback suggests you can't set a level for an entire hierarchy. In other words, you can't specify something like:

```
<logger name="com.company.app.module.**" level="ERROR"/>
```

but instead you must specify:

```
<logger name="com.company.app.module.a" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="com.company.app.module.a.b" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="com.company.app.module.a.b.c" level="ERROR"/>
```

Is there no shorthand for an entire subpackage hierarchy?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you read the manual and have a look at [the example configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#rootElement). You specify a "hierarchy" without wildcard characters. Example

```
<logger name="com.company.app.module" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="com.company.app.module.a" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="com.company.app.module.a.b" level="INFO"/>
```

The most specific logger wins. Effective level for `com.company.app.module.a.b` and below will be `INFO`. For `com.company.app.module.a` and below it will be `DEBUG`, except for `com.company.app.module.a.b`. And so on...

Comment: But suppose I want all packages within `com.company.app.module` to `INFO`, won't one line do? That is the issue i am finding.

Comment: so just use <logger name="com.company.app.module" level="INFO"/> and remove the other loggers for any package below com.company.app.module

Comment: Hi Sridhar, I have the same requirement. Mentioning <logger name="com.company.app.module" level="INFO"/> didn't work for packages under this hierarchy. Did you find a solution?